# find img tag by src value and add new attribute in img tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image

If I have 5 images into the HTML page. I want to search 2 images by it's `src` attribute value and add a new attribute to the image tag.

**The restriction** is I can't search `img` tag by any `id` or `class` attribute value, I have only `src` value. In below code,

I want to search 2 img tag which has src value like **img_src_1** and **img_src_2** and want to add a new attribute in both `img` tag **nopin="nopin"**.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // find img tag by src value and add new attribute nopin="nopin" into this img tag
            var img_src_1 = "https://example.com/image-3.jpg";
            var img_src_2 = "https://example.com/image-5.jpg";

            // find images with src url value is img_src_1 & img_src_2
            var result1 = jQuery('img').find('src', img_src_1);
            var result2 = jQuery('img').find('src', img_src_2);

            // add new attribute nopin="nopin" in both img tag

        });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>My Gallery Page</h1>
        <p>My Image 1</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 2</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-2.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 3</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-3.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 4</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-4.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 5</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-5.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
    </body>
</html>
```

**Resultant HTML** should be like this after page loads

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>My Gallery Page</h1>
        <p>My Image 1</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 2</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-2.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 3</p>
        <img nopin="nopin" src="https://example.com/image-3.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 4</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-4.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 5</p>
        <img nopin="nopin" src="https://example.com/image-5.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
    </body>
</html>
```

Any help really appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: I am really thankful to all you for quick responses. I got the exact solution to my problem and you provided it fastly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this by using jQuery's attribute selector, then using `attr()` to add the `nopin` attribute.

It's worth noting however that `nopin` is a non-standard attribute which may cause some issues with HTML validity. I'd suggest using `data-nopin` instead, if possible.

```js
jQuery(function($) {
  var img_src_1 = "https://example.com/image-3.jpg";
  var img_src_2 = "https://example.com/image-5.jpg";

  $(`img[src="${img_src_1}"], img[src="${img_src_2}"]`).attr('nopin', 'nopin');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My Gallery Page</h1>
<p>My Image 1</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 2</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-2.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 3</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-3.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 4</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-4.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 5</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-5.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
```

Answer (score 3):

please try below simple and easy solution:

```
        var img_src_1 = "https://example.com/image-3.jpg";
        var img_src_2 = "https://example.com/image-5.jpg";
        jQuery("img").each(function() {
        if(jQuery(this).attr("src") == img_src_1 || jQuery(this).attr("src") == img_src_2)
          {
            jQuery(this).attr("nopin", "nopin");
          }
       });
```

Comment: I would at least suggest to change `jQuery(this).attr("src")` in `this.src` and make an array lookup

Comment: @fcalderan are talking about this `if(jQuery(this.src).attr("src") == img_src)`?

Answer (score 2):

Use this selector `img[src="'+img_src_1+'"]` not `find`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // find img tag by src value and add new attribute nopin="nopin" into this img tag
  var img_src_1 = "https://example.com/image-3.jpg";
  var img_src_2 = "https://example.com/image-5.jpg";

  // I want to find images with src url value is img_src_1 & img_src_2 and add new attribute nopin="nopin"
  var result1 = $('img[src="'+img_src_1+'"]');
  var result2 = $('img[src="'+img_src_2+'"]');
  result1.attr('nopin','nopin');
  result2.attr('nopin','nopin');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My Gallery Page</h1>
<p>My Image 1</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 2</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-2.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 3</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-3.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 4</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-4.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 5</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-5.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
```

**Recommended version:**

No need to use full URL, just write image name and find it by this selector `img[src*="'+img_name+'"]` then, use `data` for attribute.

```js
var img_src_1 = "image-3.jpg";
var img_src_2 = "image-5.jpg";

$('img[src*="' + img_src_1 + '"], img[src*="' + img_src_2 + '"]').attr('data-nopin', 'nopin');
```

```css
img[data-nopin] {
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My Gallery Page</h1>
<p>My Image 1</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 2</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-2.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 3</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-3.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 4</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-4.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

<p>My Image 5</p>
<img src="https://example.com/image-5.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try following

```
var result1 = $('img[src="'+ img_src_1 + '"]');
var result2 = $('img[src="'+ img_src_2 + '"]');
result1.attr("nopin", "nopin");
result2.attr("nopin", "nopin");
```

For reference, [jQuery Attribute Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 1):

Loop the image and find the src of image with attr. Check src of image and if the condition match add new attribute to element with attr() function.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // find img tag by src value and add new attribute nopin="nopin" into this img tag
            var img_src_1 = "https://example.com/image-3.jpg";
            var img_src_2 = "https://example.com/image-5.jpg";

            // I want to find images with src url value is img_src_1 & img_src_2 and add new attribute nopin="nopin"
            var result1 = jQuery('img').find('src', img_src_1);
            var result2 = jQuery('img').find('src', img_src_2);
            $('img').each(function(){
              if($(this).attr('src') == img_src_1 || $(this).attr('src') == img_src_2) {
              $(this).attr('nopin', 'nopin');
              
              }
            });
        });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>My Gallery Page</h1>
        <p>My Image 1</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-1.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 2</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-2.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 3</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-3.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 4</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-4.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">

        <p>My Image 5</p>
        <img src="https://example.com/image-5.jpg" width="200px" height="200px">
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use *vanilla-JS*

```
/* retrieve images ($= means "attribute ending with") 
 * Note how easy is to look for several images (no need to write
 * ugly long and error-prone comparisons with ||), you just select them 
 * as you would do it in CSS 
 */ 
var imagesNoPin = document.querySelectorAll(
                 '[src $= "-3.jpg"], 
                  [src $= "-5.jpg"]');

/* set the attribute for each image. Note that you don't need to loop
 * over ALL images, as in other answers: you have already found them
 * before via the js-native querySelectorAll() method
 */
[].forEach.call(imagesNoPin, function(img) {
   img.setAttribute('nopin', 'nopin'); // with an attribute
   // img.dataset.nopin = "nopin"      // with a data-nopin attribute (suggested)
});

/* same result with spread [...] operator */
// [...imagesNoPin].map((img) => img.setAttribute('nopin', 'nopin'));
```

> [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/aGjeBM?editors=0110)

(In the example the images with the `nopin` attribute have been decorated with an `outline` in CSS)

Comment: for far-future readers: you will appreciate this lack of jQuery in my answer. I'm sure. I know. When I see jQuery everywhere for any task I can feel the pain of every developer pursuing passionate craftsmanship. I can hear you, I see. I hug you all.

Answer (score 1):

Following code can help you.

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function(){
            // find img tag by src value and add new attribute nopin="nopin" into this img tag
            var img_src_1 = "https://example.com/image-3.jpg";
            var img_src_2 = "https://example.com/image-5.jpg";

            // I want to find images with src url value is img_src_1 & img_src_2 and add new attribute nopin="nopin"
            jQuery('img[src="' + img_src_1 + '"]').attr("nopin" ,"nopin" );
            jQuery('img[src="' + img_src_2 + '"]').attr("nopin" ,"nopin" );

        });
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this - Used Javascript for internal code. Actually you don't need Jquery for that too (unnecessary increasing the bandwidth overhead).

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-FgpCb/KJQlLNfOu91ta32o/NMZxltwRo8QtmkMRdAu8=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <h1>My Gallery Page</h1>
    <p>My Image 1</p>
    <img src="https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/sample_7.png" width="200px" height="200px">

    <p>My Image 2</p>
    <img src="https://software-carpentry.org/files/2014/01/novice-sample.png" width="200px" height="200px">

    <p>My Image 3</p>
    <img src="https://software-carpentry.org/files/2014/01/novice-sample.png" width="200px" height="200px">

    <p>My Image 4</p>
    <img src="https://bellard.org/bpg/2.png" width="200px" height="200px">

    <p>My Image 5</p>
    <img src="https://bellard.org/bpg/2.png" width="200px" height="200px">
</body>
<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        // find img tag by src value and add new attribute nopin="nopin" into this img tag
        var img_src_1 = "https://software-carpentry.org/files/2014/01/novice-sample.png";
        var img_src_2 = "https://www.drupal.org/files/issues/sample_7.png";

        // I want to find images with src url value is img_src_1 & img_src_2 and add new attribute nopin="nopin"
        var result = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
        for(var i=0;i<result.length;i++){
            if(result[i].src==img_src_1 || result[i].src==img_src_2){
                result[i].setAttribute("nopin", "nopin");
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
```